# Updating Splash Screen Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: boot, themes, plymouth

I looked at this link to change the splash screen [Link for Splash Screen Change](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/customize-boot-splash-screen-logo-linux/)

I want to install this splash screen [Link For Splash Screen Download](https://avtrkrb.deviantart.com/art/Hydra-571572206)

But on trying this approach, i do not have a themes folder in the /lib/plymouth folder but i have a folder in the /usr/share/plymouth/themes folder.

Can anybody help me in updating the splash screen properly?

Answer (score 1):

The theme problem should be solved by performing the following steps

1. Update the path from `/lib/plymouth/themes/` to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`.
2. Run

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
   ```

   and choose the theme number.
3. Run

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The portion of the linked guide titled "**Update and Move Old Themes**" likely doesn't apply to you; you can skip it.

It appears to be for people who recently *upgraded* to Ubuntu 16.04 from an earlier version, and it sounds like you *started* with Ubuntu 16.04, since you already have a folder `/usr/share/plymouth/themes`.

To install the linked splash screen, just follow the "Installation Instructions" on the link, except replace `/lib/plymouth/themes/` to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes` throughout.

Comment: I did the replacing part and i also did the update part as specified in the article but the new splash screen was not reflected.This is the commadn i used- sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/Hydra/hydra.plymouth 100

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the file /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth, than you may find the path link to the new theme is not correct. You should modify the right path yourself in default.plymouth before update-initramfs.